# Create a criteria in Grails

Tags: grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I got two domains on my project, first is Applicant and other is Screening.

On Applicant I got:

- String name
- String age

On Screening I got:

- String status
- belongsTo: [applicant: Applicant]

Now I would like to get all applicants with age <30 and status is hired

Here my code:

```
def applicant = Applicant.queryForApp(params.age)

queryForApp{age->
lt('age', age)
}
```

However that applicants must have status is hired. I don't know how to filter that applicant with status is "Hired" because, it's on another domain class.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Currently not possible since the relationship between `Applicant` and `Screening` is unidirectional. There is no way to query this using criteras unless you add `Screening` to the `Applicant`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following criteria should work (not tested):

```
List<Applicant> applicants = Screening.withCriteria {
    eq 'status', 'HIRED'
    applicant {
        lt 'age', 30
    }
    projections {
        property 'applicant'
    }
}
```

Comment: 500 thanks for this answer :), where do you learn it from, bro? I checked grails documents, but not much example.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I've learned after doing a lot of projects with Grails :-P.  

In the documentation http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria, section "Querying with Projections", there's a link to the Hibernate Projections documentation.